# self.postMessage and onMessage don't work for a context item

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, contextmenu, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to develop an addon for Firefox (using the latest version of JetPack) that sends some AJAX data on the click on a context item. However, unfortunately it seems I have hit some problem.

Please see the code below - I have tried to make it as simple as possible to understand.

```
// file main.js
var contextMenu = require("context-menu");
var data = require("self").data;

exports.main = function(options, callbacks) {
    var contextMenuItemContentScriptFiles = [data.url("content.js")];

    var menuItemSelection = contextMenu.Item({
        label: "This is a test",
        contentScriptFile: contextMenuItemContentScriptFiles,
        context: contextMenu.SelectionContext(),

                onMessage: function (testVar) {                    
                            alert(testVar);                    
                }                                
    });
};

// file content.js
self.on("click", function (node, data) {
        alert("before posting");
        self.postMessage("messagePosted");
        alert("after posting");
});
```

The code alerts *"before posting"* and *"after posting"* but it doesn't alert *"messagePosted"* as I was expecting.

Can you please help me at finding the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem.

I had to use console.log, not alert from the main script.